# R crashes with segfault when loading certain packages

Tags: r

**Edit: re-installing all packages fixed the issue. After upgrading R and Bioconductor**

R crashes when loading certain packages, like DESeq2 and tidyverse. I think this occured after I upgraded Bioconductor, but not sure. I have MacOSX 10.12.4 (Sierra) This is with a fresh start of R and trying to load tidyverse (v. 3.3.2):

```
> library(tidyverse)

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
 4: namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),     versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
 5: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
 6: asNamespace(ns)
 7: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
 8: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 9: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
10: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
11: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
12: tryCatch({    attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc    ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)}, error = function(e) {    P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e)))         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])    else ""    msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s",         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))    if (logical.return)         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)    else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)})
13: library(tidyverse)
```

sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0
```

Comment: What OS, package versions...?

Comment: Forgot that. OSX 10.12 (sierra). Added OS and sessionInfo() to question

Comment: This is not the place for bug reports. Try R-SIG-Mac or R-devel: https://www.r-project.org/mail.html